# Remote desktop window shortcut

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, productivity

When I am logged into another machine, is there keyboard shortcut to switch to local machine and vice versa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go into the RDC options and then to the *Local Recourses* tab you can change "*Apply Windows key combinations*" to "*On this computer*" (if it isn't already), this will allow you to alt tab from the remote connection to your programs behind it. (Should work in both full screen and windowed modes.

Otherwise if you're using RDC in full screen you can press CTRL + ALT + BREAK to switch it to window mode allowing you to click behind it and give focus to what ever you click as per normal.

Comment: +1 thanks for the answer, it has been a lifesaver.